# Proof and compute derivative in point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image: f(x)]

show that f(x) derivative in x=0.5 and compute f'(0.5).

I tried to derivate f(x) without success.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{2 n (2 n+1)}x^{2 n+1}$$
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{2 n}x^{2n}=\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{ n}x^{2n}$$ Let $x^2=t$ and recognize a well know series. Go back to $x$ and replace $x$ by the number you want.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us much to go on and should show lore of your working. Differentiating term by term leads to the possibility
$$f'(x) \overset{? }{=} \sum \frac{(-1)^n}{2n} x^{2n} $$
Where the question is because we need to verify whether this series converges or for what values of x it converges.

With these hints you need to ask yourself: where (if at all) does this series converge? If you answer I will update the answer and we can look at the value at $x = 0.5$ together.

Comment: The radius of convergence is [-1,1] according to Convergence test. We need to verify that f(x) derivative in x=0.5 and compute f'(1/2) if that true.

Comment: Hint: it's also an *alternating series.* in any case if you're happy the series converges in the stated interval, then you're good because $x=1/2$ is in the interval. Now you just have to calculate the series at that point. Can you finish?